# Pattern for a database with only one thread access - Python

Tags: python, database, multithreading

I'm trying to program in python a database that can only be accessed by a single thread at a time and I am wondering which is the best way to program it. My DB is a singleton and ideally I would like that every module of my program could get the instance and perform some operations, all of them methods of my DB class. In other words, DB would be a monitor and a singleton. One way to do this would be to decorate every method in DB with the following:

```
def lock(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with DB.lock_db:
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except:
                self.conn.commit()
                self.conn.close()
    return wrapper
```

but the problem with this is that I can't call a method of DB from the body of another method of DB.

A second approach would be to define methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` in which I lock the access in `__enter__` and unlock it in `__exit__`. In this case I would have to use `with` every time I want to use the database, so it has the problem that a user (or myself) that uses my DB and forgets about `with` can have concurrency problems. Also, If I have a class A and a method of it uses the database and calls a method of B which also uses the database, the `with` locks the database, so I have the instance from A to B in the call, making the program less granular. Note that in both cases I close nicely the database in case that an exception is raised.

My question is, how could I program the database in such a way that it is a monitor, in which a method of the DB can be called from a method of the DB without deadlock and such that all this process is transparent to the user of my DB? (not like in the second approach). Ideally, DB would be a singleton, although I don't have any problem if it's not.

Comment: You could define "private" methods without the decorator (starting the method name with `_`) and only use these private methods inside other methods. The user can use decorated methods (without `_`).

Comment: True, that does the trick. I'm also interested in knowing which the "right way" of doing these kind of things would be. I mean, the best design when using a database that can only be accessed by a thread at a time